# Date format in csv and importing to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, csv, date

I am studying Microsoft Power BI and I am trying the connectivity between power BI and SQL server.
I have model data in csv and i am trying to import the data from .csv file to SQL table using import wizard.
However the date in csv is not recognized as date format even if we manually select the data type data in import wizard.
The reason is being the mixed date format, i.e. in the .csv file date column, the dates are in two formats one is MM/DD/YYYY and another is DD-MM-YYYY like below
8/26/1961 - MM/DD/YYYY (set as General as in Format option)
07-03-1915 - DD-MM-YYYY (set as Date in Format option)

When i try to enforce the date format MM-DD-YYYY format, both are not set properly. 2nd format changes to 3rd July instead of 7thMarch.

I need to set both format to one common date format before inserting into SQL table, without changing the actual data.

Comment: Import the date field as text, check the format and then modify and then save each one appropriately.. Hopefully you are saving it into a date column in your SQL table.

Comment: So are these values in the *same* column? If so, you have a far more fundamental problem if I am honest; what ever process is creating your data is doing it poorly.

Comment: You tell us how you know that a value of "05/02/2020" is either May 2 or Feb 5.

Comment: You mean one column is format `MM/DD/YYYY` and another column has format `DD-MM-YYYY` ? If it's different formats in the same column, you need to fix that first. Like, split all values that contain `/` into a separate column or something.

Comment: @ Peter Smith - Thanks for the imput Will try this and update here how it goes.

Comment: @ Larnu - Yes I agree the data is poorly handled but I got this data from an online tutorial for studying power bi and its in .csv files. I wanted to try generating the reports from SQL server with same data using direct query. thats how i ended up with this formatting issue.

Comment: @ SMor - In general, "05/02/2020" can either be May 2 or Feb 5, however I concluded the format as MM/DD/YYYY for this, as there were other entries following the same format and found one to be 8/26/1961 which clearly says it is mm/dd/yyyy.